# Python: Prevent quotes being written to CSV

Tags: python, list

I am creating a save/load system that uses CSV files. An average CSV save file would look like this:

```
name1a,RGB,1,|[0, 0, 1]|
name2a,RGB,1,|[0, 1, 0]|
name3a,RGB,1,|[0, 1, 1]|
name1b,RGB,2,|[0, 0, 1]|
Head2b,RGB,2,|[0, 1, 0]|
Head3b,RGB,2,|[0, 1, 1]|
```

The last item between the `|`s refers to a code, and is stored as one item (the `|`s make a string literal rather than 3 items). I'm saving the files like this:

```
writer.writerow(name, type, slaveNumber, '|' + str(fix.code) + '|'])
```

where `code` is a list such as `[0, 1, 1]`.

I expected to get something like this:

```
Head3b,RGB,2,|[0, 1, 1]|
```

but instead I get:

```
Head3b,RGB,2,|"[0, 1, 1]"|
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: what is `fix` in your code?

Comment: Change `str(fix.code)` to `str(fix.code).strip('"')` and it will remove any unwanted quotes.

Comment: Cannot reproduce if `fix.code` is a list or a string. Voting to close for that reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `escapechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`

**Ex:**

```
import csv
with open(filename2, "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, escapechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerow(["Head3b","RGB",2,"|",[0, 1, 1],"|"])

    #or writer.writerow(["Head3b","RGB",2,"|["+ ",".join(list(map(str, [0, 1, 1]))) +"]|"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce, but the csv module is smart enough to add quotes when needed:

```
import csv

with open("file.csv", "w", newline="") as fd:
    writer = csv.writer(quotechar = "|"
    writer.write("name1a","RGB",1,str([0, 0, 1]))
```

File content is as expected:

```
name1a,RGB,1,|[0, 0, 1]|
```